# SQL select how to insert column name and provide value

Tags: sql

How do you add a column to a select statement and assign a static value, when the column does not exist?

name | address | vacationing | Zipcode

So for the example columns above, I would like to create the column on the fly of "vacationing" whose value will be assigned No for each record.  I don't want to insert this column in the table permanently.

Thanks

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, address, 'No' as vacationing, Zipcode from mytable;
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT Name, Address, 'No' AS Vacationing, Zipcode
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a column that only exists for some of the records, and not all of them.  Either create it permanently or if you like, create another table and JOIN it using the `name` or `id` or whatever it is you use in this table as a primary key.